# Facebook 'likes' description not showing on timelines

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I cannot make the 'Description' work from facebook like no matter how much I try. I made a simple html page to test, I have debugged it shows no problems, the description is in the debugger, The picture shows up, the title and link shows up but not the description. This is just on the timeline, the main account page the description does show up. I have tried other peoples likes and their description shows up, so I figure its something I am doing wrong.

When I click the like, it shows the description as if its going to place it on the timeline but it never does.

http://shoomblitz.com/pin/stickynotes/test.html

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Test for TEST PAGE" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://shoomblitz.com/pin/stickynotes/test.html" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Patern_test.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Test Description for TEST PAGE This is a another test" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1405766033026419" />
```

Comment: I tried to post the meta code i am using but this thing stripped out the code :(